# Why is Gallery So Slow / Accessing GoogleLoginService?

Tags: android, authentication, gallery

I'm working on an app which allows users to view images, so I'm sending an intent to let the Gallery display the image. For some reason, it takes several seconds to display the image. LogCat shows it trying to connect to "GoogleLoginService"? Why does gallery connect to the internet? Can this be turned off on the phone or in code?

```
I/CacheService(19326): Preparing DiskCache for all thumbnails.
I/CacheService(19326): DiskCache ready for all thumbnails.
I/ActivityManager( 1433): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW     dat=file:///mnt/sdcard/x/attachments/68efeba8-7f0c-47bf-b7d7-d714f29f99c7.jpg typ=image/* cmp=com.cooliris.media/.Gallery }
I/Gallery (19326): onCreate
D/GoogleLoginService( 1601): onBind: Intent { act=android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator cmp=com.google.android.gsf/.loginservice.GoogleLoginService }
I/RenderView(19326): First Draw
D/GoogleLoginService( 1601): onBind: Intent { act=android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator cmp=com.google.android.gsf/.loginservice.GoogleLoginService }
I/ActivityManager( 1433): Displayed activity com.cooliris.media/.Gallery: 477 ms (total 477 ms)
D/GoogleLoginService( 1601): onBind: Intent { act=android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator cmp=com.google.android.gsf/.loginservice.GoogleLoginService }
I/GridLayer(19326): Slot changing from -1 to -1
```

Comment: Does this happen on both device and emulator? 

If you want speed, the (obviously) fastest option would be to show the image in a full screen `Activity`. Ans if you have more than one image you can use a `ViewPager` to show them in a carousel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The device is using the **Gallery3D** application which integrates with Picasa - login to Picasa is handled by the Google account authenticator. Most of the account fiddling happens on a separate thread however (if I remember that app correctly) - and doesn't really impact the startup.

It's almost always the gallery thumbnails fetch that's the culprit.